# Why does my soft-body fly around?

Tags: physics, soft-body

## **[My blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34908)**

I'm playing around with the Softbody engine in Blender to create something like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NhDM.gif)**:

[image: what I'm trying to go for]

...but I've had no luck yet. Whenever I try to simulate, I get very strange results like **[this](http://gfycat.com/HoarseIllinformedBluetickcoonhound)** or **[this](http://gfycat.com/ThatFewBullmastiff)**, shown here (links are better quality):

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Although they're hilarious and fun to show to my friends, they're not **[what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NhDM.gif)**.

Comment: These gifs is so entertaining! +1

Comment: Although I could sit here watching rubber chicken man all day, it wouldn't solve your problem. Could you upload a more informative (albeit not as entertaining) screen-shot of the physics panel for him? Also check to make sure he's not parented to anything. Thanks!

Comment: @ARadish He added a .blend

Comment: oh... right at the top. fantastic.... (I feel stupid) :)

Comment: This is hilarious....!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay the problem of flying around appears to be the collision ball size calculation. You had it set to average. When I set it to minimal, it worked. I admit, I have no idea why this happened, it may have been a collision fight with the plane, but changing it does fix your problem.

I also tweaked a few other settings to get it to look like the target animation, it's not perfect, but it's better than what you had. :)

- Turned off Stiff quads (you don't want anything stiff on this guy.)
- Turned friction up to 1.00 (that may have been part of your problem, he's as slippery as an eel)
- Angled him a little so his legs don't fold up. (didn't work real well, but I'm sure if you try you can get it right)
- And (optional) changed skin texture to something shiny so I could see bounding and stretching problems. (also that skin texture is disturbing :D)

So the effect isn't quite right, but hey! he doesn't head for Florida every time you hit play. Noodling him is your job as the artist. Have fun...

[image]

[image]

Comment: self collision seems to have an effect too, i had better results with minimal.

Comment: Good point. Minimal worked best for me too.